# Easiest to use DAW with sample sounds

Tags: daw

I'm really new to DAW's. I just want a really simple free one with out of the box music samples. I am not entirely sure what they are called (the different sounds you can add as free and out of the box).

After playing around with it, I wouldn't mind paying to buy some sample sounds ones which are better quality for that DAW.

Comment: While Johnatha did provide a good answer, this type of question is not on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of free DAWs, and they bring some sample sounds, like instruments, effects, voices, etc. But I guess you don't need to choose the DAW because of the samples. You can find free sample packs on the internet and be free to choose the DAW you want or you think is more easy to use.

In this link you have some free DAWs: https://thehomerecordings.com/free-daw/

> What is the easiest DAW for beginners? Garageband is one of the
> easiest DAWs out there to learn, however it is only available for iOS
> devices. If you’re a Windows user then Studio One Prime or Audacity
> might be good places to start.

In the other hand you have to search for free samples:

https://www.musicradar.com/news/the-best-free-music-samples-and-loop-download-sites-on-the-web

https://www.musictech.net/guides/buyers-guide/the-best-websites-for-free-samples-in-2021/

I hope it helps you to decide how to start.